# Sync Outlook calendar to SharePoint online calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

It is possible to display SharePoint online Calendar in Outlook Calendar.

But is there any way to sync Outlook 365 Calendar to SharePoint Online? One of the way that I found was as below:

Connect the SharePoint Online Calendar to Outlook and then Open outlook and manually copy events from outlook calendar to SPO calendar.

I want to know if there is any other way of automatic sync of Outlook with SPO calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no way to get this done, the sync is not supported for SharePoint online. Also the overlay calendar for Exchange doesn't work in SPO( [Exchange calendar issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-dont-office365-exchange-calendar-overlays-work/9f6b0c0f-e82c-4953-b8ed-ae7422851307))
All you can do is build AAD app use outlook/Graph APIs get the information from Outlook and display it in SharePoint ([Check this blog](https://codeatwork.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/using-outlook-rest-apis-in-sharepoint-online/) ). If you want to display it in Calendar view you will have to use plugins like Full calendar to do that

Answer (score 0):

To display SharePoint Online calendar in Outlook Calendar we need to sync, please follow below steps for syncing

1. Login to SharePoint Online site.
2. Create Your Calendar (if not exists).
3. Open the Calendar and click "Calendar" tab at top left corner.
4. Click "Connect to Outlook". Then it will ask for confirmation, click "Yes".
5. Now go to Outlook Calendar and check.

Comment: This is in the wrong direction per OP.

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy, but you have to pay attention to the Flow of things.

The Calendar Must exist in SharePoint First. So, If your Calendar is already in Outlook, you need to log into SharePoint and create your calendar where ever you want it to go. Then you will click the "Calendar" tab on top left, and then click "Sync to Outlook". This will sync the blank calendar to your outlook.
Next, you need to go to your main calendar you want to sync, and change the View to "All Items", you then want to copy all items and go to your new calendar change view to All Items, and paste in your items. This will get all the items synced up to SharePoint.

Now you just need to tell everyone to go into SharePoint and sync that calendar down to outlook. Now just make sure everyone uses that calendar.

So, whatever you do, the calendar needs to start in SharePoint.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not what I am looking for. I wanted to know if there is any way we can eliminate the manual steps. Any automated way to sync these.

Comment: I'm going to say that even though it sounds like a good approach, you will be missing out on app's calendar features, as you can't bring in a SharePoint list calendar into mobile and therefore alerts and things like that won't work.
If that's not an issue, it still could bring complications.